# How to change page backgroundcolor with switch in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to change background color on my page when switch is true and false.So far I have

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App9"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App9.MainPage" x:Name="main" BackgroundColor="{Binding Display}">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:Class1/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    <Switch x:Name="toggle" Toggled="Switch_Toggled"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (toggle.IsToggled == true)
            {
                class1.Display=Color.White;
            }
        }
```

And class1

```
public class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    private Color display;

    public Color Display
    {
        get
        {
            return display;
        }
        set
        {
            if (display != value)
            {
                display = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Display));


            }
        }
    }
```

So when switch is on the background should be white.But it wont changed.I am not sure how to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: What is the default color of your page? And what color would be set when switch is un-toggled?

Comment: white and when is off should be white and black when is on

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the Display setter is it hit when you toggle the switch?

Comment: yes but background color wont changed

Comment: Show the first lines of your xaml please (till the `mc:Ignorable="d"` line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the simplest way would be to use triggers for that purpose.

> Triggers allow you to express actions declaratively in XAML that change the appearance of controls based on events or property changes. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers))

You can bind a `DataTrigger` to the value of a `Switch` to change the appearance of another control. I built a small example with a `Switch` that changes the `BackgroundColor` of a `BoxView`, just for demonstration purposes:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Switch x:Name="Switch" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Crimson">
        <BoxView.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger TargetType="BoxView"  
                         Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switch}, Path=IsToggled}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="CornflowerBlue" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </BoxView.Triggers>
    </BoxView>
</StackLayout>
```

I've added a `DataTrigger` to `BoxView.Triggers` that reacts to the `Switch.IsToggled` property. If it's set to `True` (see the `Value` property), the `Setter` will be applied to the `BoxView` and `BackgroundColor` will be set to `CornflowerBlue`.

In your case it'd be something like

```xml
<ContentPage.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentPage"  
                 Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switch}, Path=IsToggled}"
                 Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
    </DataTrigger>
</ContentPage.Triggers>
```

There is no need for using `BindingContext` in this case.

**Works:**

[image: GIF displaying the trigger in action, changing the Background color of a page]

Comment: but i need to change content page background

Comment: @MathProblem Please see my edit, I thought that transferring the solution to the `ContentPage` was trivial.

Comment: @MathProblem Added a GIF displaying the `Trigger` in action. Unfortunately the MOV to GIF converter messed up the end, it's not that choppy in real life ;)

Comment: Ok perfect but i need databinding because the color should change on different ContentPages

Comment: @MathProblem Please note that setting the `Display` property of `Class1` won't have an effect on other pages either, because you create an instance per page with the `<local:Class1 />` tag. You'd have to inject an instance in the pages or at least resolve a singleton from code behind for a shared state between the pages.

Comment: so i tried to test this             <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding Display}" /> but not work

Comment: @MathProblem Is it always ColorA and ColorB or is there any logic behind it?

Comment: Yes when switch is on color = black else white